# Looking for free/oss multiple window text editor (Perl + other lang) for view/edit different sections of same file at same time (windows platform)

Tags: windows, text, view, editor

I'm looking for a free/oss multiple window code text editor (Perl + other languages) for viewing/editing different sections of same file. Can you recommend one for Windows platform?

Currently I use Notepad++ which is good and has a tab for each file. But it doesn't allow opening the same file more than once in different tabs to be able to view different parts of the file. I would also like to 'tear-off' a tab to make a new window (just like in Google Chrome) so I can see different parts of the same file side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++ (5.9.3 at least) right click on the tab of a version and select `Clone to Other View`.

Voila! Editing the same file in two different tabs. You can also drag the tab out of the window and 'drop' it on the desktop to open another instance of Notepad++.

Comment: +1 yes! This is JUST what I need - right click on the tab for the options you describe. Thanks @BeRecursive ! I would accept your answer now, but it says I can do this in 9 minutes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

emacs is a good fit. its almost-clone (but really not the same) [epsilon](http://www.lugaru.com/) is lighter and easier to begin with.

*(i just remembered that, although i have a full version of epsilon, it is not free... too bad, because it's a very good editor)*

Comment: +1 for Epsilon - it's always good to learn about new editors. I'm always willing to pay a reasonable amount of money if the product is good (and reward the efforts of the creators in doing so :) ) Thanks @Adrien Plisson

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com). I've switched to it From Notepad++. Works on Windows OS X and Linux. I find the Minimap very useful.

You can get multiple views on a file using "New View into" from the file menu.

Comment: +1 Wow I really like the Minimap. A. LOT. !!! Never heard of this or seen this before. I may get this for my Mac! Thanks @Actel